# Non GUI Jmeter run with Listener

Tags: jmeter

For non-gui JMeter, there is much info available about how to take a report. which is basically done by mentioning report name in command and not adding any listener in Test Plan

But I use a different approach. Please confirm whether it compromises the performance of JMeter or it is as good as mentioned in the 1st paragraph.

I add Listener in Test plan and mention filename in the listener.  Do my configure settings. Close the Test plan and run it in NON-GUI mode with the following command.

`jmeter -n -t ProjectName.jmx`

Comment: The OP's english need improve(I don't quite understand what is asking).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use first approach, in which you define the path of report file within your command. It is considered most efficient approach.

An alternative to above is adding 'simple data writer' listener to your test plan. Define the path of report in this listener and run the jmeter script from command line. This is also resource efficient approach. It is similar to your approach. Only difference is that instead of enabling multiple listeners, enable only one listener that is 'simple data writer'. You can later use report generated by this listener in different listeners and generate graphs as required.

To cut it short, resource usage depends upon on choice of listener. Command line mode uses lightest listener by default. If you don't want to mention it in command-line; then enable 'simple data writer' with in your GUI plan. Hope you understand the concept.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In fact the concern is after the run I wish to see data in Summary report foe bpth pass/fail requests also for failed requests I wish to save requesta nd response data as well. Now if I add only one report through command prompt....then to meet my above requirements I will have to save request & Response for even passed results (which is quite heavy) So I though of saving 2 reports one to see Summary report and other to see only errors with detail

Comment: You can achieve your objectives in much efficient way. Donot use summary report. Read point 4 and 5 in this article to learn more.. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/nine-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure

Comment: use this property in user.properties file.. jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true

Answer (score 0):

I want to use the following Listeners, but as part of my *.jtl file results

1. View Results Tree
2. Aggregate Report
3. jp@gc - Response Times Percentiles
4. jp@gc - Response Times over Time

Now, since high volume Load Tests run in non-gui mode, so these Listeners have no value. But perhaps they have value when we generate reports after we generate the jtl file. How can that be acheived? Is there some setting in user.properties? Which can enable these listeners? at Report time generation.